# Why can we choose such a $m$? Where does the $m$ come from?

Tags: analysis

Let $a_{n,g}$ be the number of ways of putting down g $\ell$'s on the discrete interval $[0,n-1]$ with the $\ell's$ separated by at least two $0$'s. Let $a_n=\sum_{g=0}^n a_{n,g}$.

Suppose that
$$
\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\ln \sum_{g=0}^n a_{n,g}^2=2\ln p.~~~~(*)
$$
(I think for my question is doet not really matter where this comes from and what $p$ is.)

Now to my question:

Quote:

> Let $\varepsilon >0$. Using $(*)$ choose $m$ such that
>   $$
> \frac{\ln(\sum_{g=0}^m a_{m,g}^2)}{m+2}\geqslant 2\ln p -\varepsilon.
> $$

Where does this $m$ come from? Why can we choose such an $m$?

*Could you please help me?*

----- **Edit: Here is my answer.**

There is the following characterization for the limit superior:

> > Let $(x_n)$ be a real sequence and $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Then $\limsup_n x_n=x$ iff for each $\varepsilon >0$ the following two conditions are fullfilled. (1) For almost all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ it is $x_n<x+\varepsilon$. (2) There are infinitely many $m\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $x_m>x-\varepsilon$.

(There is no problem when we write $x_m\geq x-\varepsilon$ in (2).)

It is
$$
\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n+2}\ln\sum_{g=0}^{n+2}a_{n,g}^2=\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n+2}\ln\sum_{g=0}^n a_{n,g}^2=2\ln p,
$$
because $\sum_{g=0}^{n+2}a_{n,g}^2=\sum_{g=0}^n a_{n,g}^2$ because there are no possibilities to put $(n+1)$ or $(n+2)$ $\ell$'s on $[0,n-1]$ in the desired manner and
$$
\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n+2}\ln\sum_{g=0}^n a_{n,g}^2=\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\ln\sum_{g=0}^{n}a_{n,g}^2\cdot\frac{n}{n+2}\\
=\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\ln\sum_{g=0}^n a_{n,g}^2\cdot\underbrace{\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{n+2}}_{=1}.
$$

So one can apply the above characterization of the limit superiort to the sequence $(b_n)$,
$$
b_n:=\frac{1}{n+2}\ln\sum_{g=0}^n a_{n,g}^2,
$$
saying that for $\varepsilon >0$ there are infinitely many $m\in\mathbb{N}$ with
$$
b_m\geq 2\ln p-\varepsilon.
$$
So choose such an $m$ as done in the quote.

I think that's it. Do you agree?

Comment: That's from the definition of lim sup

Comment: Could you please explain that? Because I do not see why.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_superior_and_limit_inferior

Comment: Sorry, I read over this definitions before and unfortunately do not see why the existence of that $m$ follows from that.

Comment: Look in the wiki under interpretation.  There is an N, such that for all n>N...  Pick an m > N, then massage the formula to the one that's shown.

Comment: oh, you know what, I think you typed the first formula in wrong or something.  you probably meant lim inf

Comment: No, its definitely limsup

Comment: i just hit refresh and the formula changed to 2 ln p.  can you make sure everything is right

Comment: Its right now. I added the factor 2, right. But now its right.

Comment: where are you getting these formulas?  the bottom formula is from lim inf.  you must have typed one of the two formulas in wrong.

Comment: nevermind.  it's right.

Comment: Could you please explain - ,maybe in chat?

Comment: look up in your book for the epsilon definition of lim sup.  it should follow pretty clearly.  the wiki is incomplete.

Comment: @thang pls have a look on m edited questions where i added an "idea"